# How to separate the mongoose connect method to another JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, discord.js

For my discord bot, I was thinking of separating the mongoose connect method and other initialization to a separate JS file. I was able to move everything except for the connect method. I don't know how this could be done.

Comment: Mark it as answer if it resolved your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
// Declare mongoose as global
global.mongoose = require('mongoose');

// In Separate file
const url = "Your URL";

//BUILD A CONNECTION
mongoose.connect(url).then(() => { console.log('Connected To database :)')})
.catch( err => console.log('error', err));

module.exports.mongoose = mongoose

// Schema File

const users = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
}, {
    timestamps : true
})


module.exports = mongoose.model('users', users);

// In model Path
const usersModel = require('Schemas/users')
```

now you can use usersModel to query documents/table

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I have a few doubts. Why is it exported as global? What happens if isn't global?

Comment: You can do that without exporting as global. You will need to import in all the files. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
// suppose this filename is, mongoose.db.config.js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

function mongooseConnectDB(uri) {
  mongoose
    .connect(uri, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true,
    })
    .then((result) =>
      console.log("Mongoose connected to ", result.connections[0].host)
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log("error connecting to the database", err));
}

module.exports = mongooseConnectDB;
```

- Now in your app(main.js/index.js/server.js), you can do simply like this

```
const mongooseConnectDB = require("./mongoose.db.config");
mongooseConnectDB('url_of_your_db');
```